# How to cast object of type 'especific' to type 'FileHelpers.Events.INotifyRead in Multirecording

Tags: vb.net, filehelpers

I'm trying to centralize all formatting and conversion rule in a single class especific. Using the interface INotifyRead(Of T As Class). When I implement the methods BeforeRead/AfterRead throws an exception: Unable to cast object of type 'Especific' to type 'FileHelpers.Events.INotifyRead`1[System.Object]'.

Below my code.

```
Using engine As New MultiRecordEngine(New RecordTypeSelector(AddressOf CifraRecordTypeSelector),
                                                GetType(RemessaRegistroCliente),
                                                GetType(RemessaRegistroContrato))
    Dim records = engine.ReadFile(_camArquivo)
End Using

Public NotInheritable Class RemessaRegistroCliente
    Implements INotifyRead(Of RemessaRegistroCliente)

    Public Sub AfterRead(e As AfterReadEventArgs(Of RemessaRegistroCliente)) Implements INotifyRead(Of RemessaRegistroCliente).AfterRead

    End Sub

    Public Sub BeforeRead(e As BeforeReadEventArgs(Of RemessaRegistroCliente)) Implements INotifyRead(Of RemessaRegistroCliente).BeforeRead

    End Sub
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class RemessaRegistroContrato
    Implements INotifyRead(Of RemessaRegistroContrato)

    Public Sub AfterRead(e As AfterReadEventArgs(Of RemessaRegistroContrato)) Implements INotifyRead(Of RemessaRegistroContrato).AfterRead

    End Sub

    Public Sub BeforeRead(e As BeforeReadEventArgs(Of RemessaRegistroContrato)) Implements INotifyRead(Of RemessaRegistroContrato).BeforeRead

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where is the `Especific` class? I do not see any reference to it in the code you have posted.

Comment: Sorry @shamp00 my especific class are RemessaRegistroCliente and RemessaRegistroContrato. I updated the code for clarity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `MultiRecordEngine` has no generic version, you cannot implement the generic `INotifyRead(Of T)` to handle events. Instead, assign delegates to the engine.

```
Sub Main()
    Using engine As New MultiRecordEngine(New RecordTypeSelector(AddressOf CifraRecordTypeSelector),
                                                GetType(RemessaRegistroCliente),
                                                GetType(RemessaRegistroContrato))
        AddHandler engine.BeforeReadRecord, AddressOf BeforeReadRecordHandler
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub BeforeReadRecordHandler(ByVal engine As EngineBase, ByVal e As BeforeReadEventArgs(Of Object))

End Sub
```

You'll also need to modify your classes to remove the generic interfaces:

```
Public NotInheritable Class RemessaRegistroCliente
   'your fields
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class RemessaRegistroContrato
   'your fields
End Class
```

Comment: I understand... unfortunately MultiRecordEngine has no generic version! I'll  need to cast object twice! I'll updated the code to explain!

Comment: The engine delegate event has a `BeforeReadEventArgs(Of Object)` parameter so you can cast the object to one or other of your record types. Don't use `INotifyRead` at all. Use the engine event instead.

Comment: I'm not very good with VB, but yes that looks like it will work.